# What do plugin icons mean?

Tags: intellij-idea

What do the following icons mean?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I saw [symbol reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html) but I didn't find what I want.

Comment: Did you check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/plugins-settings.html? See https://i.imgur.com/yv8WJtX.png.

Comment: Why do you ask this here and not [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reporting-issues.html#d435604e110)? Product support questions tend to be very opinion-based at Stack Overflow because people start guessing.

Comment: @CrazyCoder this is exactly what I need! You should write an answer to the question and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information can be found in [IntelliJ IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/plugins-settings.html).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Then, What is mean the minus(-) mark that edge of plugin icon?

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish above two icons now.

[image: Plug-in icon at IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3]